# how to implement pushing functionality inside UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

In my project i have one `pageviewcontroller` it's manage three viewcontrollers. First viewcontroller is a `tableviewcontroller` second one is `UIViewcontroller`  .By normally i can scroll the viewcontrollers using `pageviewcontroller` scrolling functionality. It's ok for me, but i need one more thing using `pageviewcontroller` when i select one row of `tableviewcontroller` i need to push (scroll)to second view controller. How can i do this using `pageviewcontroller`, after this i need to sroll back to firstviewcontroller.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a page control on [github link](https://github.com/NagaMallesh/MLKPageViewCtrl). This uses viewcontrollers for every page. Just use NavigationControllers instead of these viewcontrollers and set the desired view controllers as root View controller. You will be able to push and navigate through screens.